# Cannot download Vagrant box file

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I tried to do the standard 
$ vagrant up
and Vagrant give me

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

transfer closed with 100 bytes remaining to read
```

I tried to bypass this by manually downloading the box image from my browser and run it from there and I was able to play with Vagrant. But more problem arrive when I tried to download JDK in Vagrant and it also give the same error message

```
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

transfer closed with 100 bytes remaining to read
```

So I assume that there is something wrong.
I am using mac, and my Vagrant port is 8088.

I'm wondering if anyone have this error before?
Thanks

Comment: I also tried installing ubuntu in VirtualBox and the same problem happen in VirtualBox too so I guess it is not a Vagrant problem

Comment: make sure you're using the correct versions of both vagrant and virtualbox. And if all else fails, "have you tried turning it off and on again" ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just check and I am using the latest version of vagrant and virtualbox and I have been turning it on and off many times (ﾉД`)
Now that I tried to use curl to download Oracle Java 8, I notice the same problem so not sure where the problem can come from.

Comment: I found that it was a problem with my company's anti virus software blocking something. Regardless, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and forgot I was connected to my corporate VPN.  Trying again disconnected fixed it.